# Ember.js dynamic links

Tags: javascript, dynamic, ember.js

I'm trying to develop a webapp involving race results of my local running group.
Ember.js looked like a nice framework to develop the website.

My code at this very moment:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource('results', function(){
       this.resource('year');
   });
});

App.ResultsRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON("../api/api.php?method=years");
        //returns a JSON array with all the years a certain race went through => [{"year":"2008"},{"year":"2009"},{"year":"2010"}]
    },
});

App.YearRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
    //some horrible code
    }   
});
```

On the left side of my website all the years appear in a list.
When I click on a year, the race results appear on the right side.

How do I adjust the Router.map so the url looks like "www.example.com/index.html#/results/2008" when I click on the year 2008?

As a noob programmer, I have a difficult time figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('results', function(){
    this.resource('year', {path:'/:year'});
  });
});
```

Here's an example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oMAYUzIq/1/edit